# ReactJS state does not return the right value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect, react-props

### Problem:

I am building a simple chat app, in `App.js` I am saving the message history and in Screen.js I handle the input, etc.

The problem I am facing is that when I add a new message to the history it always overwrites the complete history.

### What I did:

- I added `useEffect(() => {...}, [messages]);` to App.js to check if new messages are saved - and they are.
- Then I added a `console.log(messages)` to the `addMsg()` in App.js AND in Screen.js and discovered that this console.log always returns an empty array.

I have no idea why messages returns data in the useEffect but not inside the addMsg function ...

### Code:

App.js

```
const [messages, addMessage] = useState([]); 

# this function is passed down as a prop to add new messages to the history
const addMsg = (data) => {
  console.log('  old history', messages); 

  return addMessage([...messages, data]); 
};

...

return (
  <div className="App">
    <Screen messages={messages} addMsg={addMsg} />
  </div>
)
```

This is how I call the addMsg function from Screen.js:

```
props.addMsg(data);
```

Screen.js:

```
function Screen(props) {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('props.messages', props.messages); // always returns []
  }, [props.messages]);


  const sendMsg = (msg) => {

    let data = {
      timestamp: Date.now(), 
      id: props.id, 
      msg: msg, 
      key: props.messages.length+1,  
    }; 
 
    props.addMsg(data);

  }



  return (
    <div className="screen">
      <div className="messages">
        {
          props.messages.map(obj => {
            return <Row key={obj.key} id={obj.id} timestamp={obj.timestamp} msg={obj.msg} />
          })
        }
      </div>

      <Input id={props.id} send={sendMsg} />

    </div>
  )
}
```

Basically I just pass an object to addMsg that then get's added to the history (messages) array.

I am relatively new to React and have been stuck on this for hours ...

### Clarification

It's a simple chat app. The messages array holds all messages (like a history). When I add a new message the history array get's reset but I do not know why.
When I add a message it does get added to the history array (I tested this with an useEffect handler [messages]); but I also added a console.log to the addMessage function that always tells me that my history array is empty ... I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you past the code inside Screen component ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I do pass the messages array down to the Screen.js component ...

Comment: hi! did you try another approach not using spread directly? 

const addMsg = (data) => {
  const newMessages =messages.push(data)
  return addMessage(newMessages ); 
};

Comment: @HelloThere23 I am saying can you edit your question and add the Screen.js code.

Comment: Added Screen.js code :)

Comment: Nothing seems wrong on the surface. I suggest you build a minimal reproduction of the problem on codepen.io and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `addMsg` returns `addMessage` which is a useState setter. After that the `useEffect` handlers get triggered and they already have the updated value.

But an useState setter doesn't return a value, so you'll have to adjust the `addMsg` function to return a value.

That's why you see the changed value in `useEffect` and not returned by `addMsg`

```js
const addMsg = (data) => {
  console.log('  old history', messages); 

  let newMessages = [...messages, data];
  addMessage(newMessages); 
  // After the setter call the 'messages' variable 
  // is not yet updated, so use the 'newMessages' variable.

  return newMessages
};
```

Now `addMsg` returns the new array.

Comment: Nothing is done with the returned value from addMsg, how does this help?

Comment: The question was why addMsg doesn't return any data. I've ansewered the question. What he wants to do with it is his choice

Comment: where does it say that?

Comment: I see `The problem I am facing is that when I add a new message to the history it always overwrites the complete history.` and `I have no idea why messages returns data in the useEffect but not inside the addMsg function ...` - nothing about returning *from* a function

Comment: I've updated my answer to more clarify it. My bad read it wrong

Comment: it doesn't make any sense, no-where in the code are they reading any value returned from `addMsg`. The question is worded confusingly, but I don't think your answer fits any of the possible interpretations.

Comment: Yes, i am sorry for the confusion. I am new to react and if I would do the same in vanilla JS this would be solved in seconds .. but I am learning states now :)

Comment: no, this answer doesn't make any sense - your question at least makes *some* sense :-)